# Removing OEM version of Windows, and re-installing in VM

Tags: windows, lvm

I just ordered a new Lenovo X1 with Windows 10 for work.  There will be times I'm required to run Windows, though I prefer to use Linux (Mint, currently) for most day-to-day tasks.

Question: If I create a back-up of the originally-installed copy of Windows 10 through whatever means Lenovo provides (recovery USB drive creation tool of some sort, I'm assuming), can I then re-install that copy of Windows in a VM after I get Mint up & running, or will I run into license issues when I re-home Win10 into a VM?  (This might be a Windows forum question, but I'm guessing more folks here have had experience with this.)

I'd rather go this route than dual-boot, so please don't offer that as an answer to this question.  (...though I do appreciate the advice!)

Thanks Everyone,

Shane

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a Windows license question has nothing to do with Unix or Linux. And I also fail to understand why Unix guys should have more experience with Windows' licence issues than Windows guys.

Comment: got'cha. I just assumed other Linux users had dealt with the same issue and could help shed some light for me.  I haven't received much intelligent help from the Windows forums.  (I know I can always find that here!)
Still, I'll close out the question here.

Comment: Would be interesting to know whether the idea of backing up a Windows 10 installation (and with what tools), then attempting to install it into a VirtualBox guest machine, whether Windows 10 somehow detects "hey this isn't the original machine!" or not. Would this be a SuperUser question then?

Comment: @user454038 Added this case to my answer:
Running a backup/image of the original installation to a VM will trigger reactivation of Windows which will fail since OEM-licenses are in general bound to the motherboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

citing https://superuser.com/questions/965151/can-you-transfer-a-windows-10-oem-licence-to-a-vm-while-not-running-a-windows-ho :

> In short; It will work, but is not allowed:
>
> As stated on Microsoft.com:
>
> > You are required to support the license on that original PC, but you
> >     cannot support a license that has been moved from a PC that you
> >     manufactured to one that you did not. This is one of the key reasons
> >     why **an OEM System Builder License can’t be
> >     transferred.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​**
>
> If you had a non OEM license it would have been OK to virtualize your
>   Windows, so long as you deactivate the old one.
>
> source:
>   http://www.microsoft.com/OEM/en/licensing/sblicensing/Pages/transfer_oem_licenses.aspx

Additionally you might not be able to get the Windows 10 license key since OEM keys are most of the times burned into the BIOS/UEFI.

Running a backup/image of the original installation to a VM will trigger reactivation of Windows which will fail since OEM-licenses are in general bound to the motherboard. From the official Microsoft FAQ:

> **What happens if I change my motherboard?**
>
> As it pertains to the OEM license this will invalidate the Windows 10
>   upgrade license because it will no longer have a previous base
>   qualifying license which is required for the free upgrade. You will
>   then have to purchase a full retail Windows 10 license. If the base
>   qualifying license (Windows 7 or Windows 8.1) was a full retail
>   version, then yes, you can transfer it.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/wiki/insider_wintp-insider_install/frequently-asked-questions-windows-10/5c0b9368-a9e8-4238-b1e4-45f4b7ed2fb9